# Order wordpress post by custom field value?

Tags: wordpress

Currently i have tried half internet codes ( :D ) to make this work, but with no luck.
I'm not a wordpress guru so it's quite bit hard. Basically what i want is to make plugin that will alter all post ordering across all wordpress blog based on date value in custom field.

For example i add custom field to each post (meta_key=bb_history) and (meta_value=2011-04-03).

So where i would hook or what filter should i use to get this working somehow? I guess you can use posts_where, posts_join, posts_orderby actions to make something?

Comment: You want to order the posts in the admin area or when you loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want a plug-in. Just edit your query_posts statement in the template in question.

```
query_posts($query_string . '&meta_key=YOURFIELDNAME');
```

Comment: i don't wan't to edit all template files that uses loop and add this manually.

Comment: You don't have to. Make a new template, and add this query. Then make a new page and chose this template you just made. When you visit this page, it will show the content of all your other pages.

Comment: ok anyways currently i ended up with query_posts($query_string . '&meta_key=YOURFIELDNAME&orderby=meta_value'); and put in archive.php and category.php and index.php before has_posts function.